# inheritance and generic and Dagger2

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance, dagger-2

I have two kind of fragment. One of them is `ListFragment` and the other one is `ListWithFilterFragment` that `ListWithFilterFragment extend ListFragment`. Also I have two presenter for these fragments that `ListWithFilterPresenter extend ListPresenter`. So I define separate module for presenter and separate component in Dagger. I want to inject correct presenter to these fragment but I got error

this is `ListFragment`:

```
public class ListFragment<V extends ListView> extends BaseFragment<V, ListPresenter<V>> implements ListView {
    @Inject
    ListPresenter presenter;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListPresenter createPresenter() {
    DaggerListComponent.builder().build().inject((ListFragment<ListView>) this);
    return presenter;
}
```

this is `ListWithFilterFragment`:

```
public class ListWithFilterFragment extends ListFragment<ListWithFilterView> implements ListWithFilterView {
    @Inject
    ListWithFilterPresenter presenter;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListWithFilterPresenter createPresenter() {
        DaggerListWithFilterComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

this is `ListComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ListPresenterModule.class, 
ListInteractorModule.class})
public interface ListComponent {
    void inject(ListFragment<ListView> fragment);
}
```

this is `ListWithFilterComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ListWithFilterPresenterModule.class, 
ListInteractorModule.class})
public interface ListWithFilterComponent {
    void inject(ListWithFilterFragment fragment);
}
```

and my presenters modules

```
@Module
public class ListWithFilterPresenterModule {
    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public ListWithFilterPresenter providePresenter(ListInteractor interactor) {
        return new ListWithFilterPresenter(interactor);
    }
} 

@Module
public class ListPresenterModule {
    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public ListPresenter providePresenter(ListInteractor interactor) {
        return new ListPresenter(interactor);
    }
}
```

> Error:(16, 10) error: com.sober.appModules.List.presenter.ListPresenter cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated.method.com.sober.appModules.List.presenter.ListPresenter is injected at
>   com.sober.appModules.List.ui.ListFragment.presenter
>   com.sober.appModules.List.ui.ListWithFilterFragment is injected at com.sober.appModules.List.injection.ListWithFilterComponent.inject(fragment)

Comment: Is createPresenter a method that is in a base class?

Comment: yes this is abstract method in abstract base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dagger does not do partial injections. Either it can provide all the objects, or it will fail with *cannot be provided*.

In your case `ListWithFilterComponent` cannot provide `ListPresenter` to `ListWithFilterFragment`—or rather its `ListFragment` parent.

*see comments at the end of the lines*

```
error: List.presenter.ListPresenter cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated.method.
List.presenter.ListPresenter is injected at  <- missing object
List.ui.ListFragment.presenter <- field in parent that is getting injected
List.ui.ListWithFilterFragment is injected at <- object it tries to inject
List.injection.ListWithFilterComponent.inject(fragment) <- component that's missing something
```

If you want to keep your current setup you will need to provide `ListPresenter` from your `ListWithFilterComponent` as well, or otherwise you will need to refactor your fragments so that they don't extend one another.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your response. But my ListWithFilterPresenter extend ListPresenter. Why should I need to inject ListPresenter again? I need when I use ListWithFilterFragment, Dagger just inject ListWithFilterPresenter instead of ListPresenter. You say that Dagger cannot do this?

Comment: @Saber Dagger will inject the _whole_ object, this includes any properties of the parent. It can not just inject the subclass, no. You should not inject `ListPresenter` again, but instead refactor your code and resolve this parent-child relationship, since those 2 classes don't seem like they should be related to me